# `eb list` does not show previously created envrionments in AWS console

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

To all AWS wizards out there.

I created an eb environment with the web UI. After using the eb cli to init my project with the command `eb init`, I was unable to see my already created envrionment with `eb list`.

Am I doing something wrong? Is it not the way it is supposed to work?

Comment: Can you try with `ab list --all`?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you manage to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No unfortunately.. I have since resigned myself to only use the AWS Console :)